# LDAP ACL Plugin for Zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper

I have customized a new LDAP plugin to provide basic Zookeeper Authenication. 
some thing like

`setAcl /zookeeperPath ldap:<Group>:crwda`

and when I check for the znodes

`addAuth ldap:<uid>:password`

will grant me access to the znodes

I know this can be done using the kerberos. But in my enterprise Linux Auth is doe through sssd. kerberos is not enabled.

I am afraid I have done some customization that should have not been done. Because, I did not get any reference from internet to do it.

If theare are any plugins thats been already used please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no ldap auth plugin for zookeeper. As zookeeper supports SASL kerberos authentication. But additional ACLs can be set using Active directory or LDAP group permissions. This can be achieved by implementing

```
org.apache.zookeeper.server.auth.AuthenticationProvider
```

and settng -D params as

```
-Dzookeeper.authProvider.1=class.path.to.XyzAuthenticationProvider
```

Comment: can you elaborate on the [AuthenticationProvider] implementation ? do you have a github link to a project ? I am trying to make confluent trust Azure AD ACLs and its not working so far